# Matlab: Editor: Change text color of numbers

Tags: matlab, editor

In Notepad++, coded numbers are highlighted in orange.
This is very useful in Matlab; however, I do not see the option in its settings.

Does a method exist?

Comment: In the syntax highlighting preferences there is no separate option for coloring a number literal, no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the MATLAB editor doesn't have a colored highlight for numbers.

Comment: Matlab FAIL. That is sad !